# sharepoint 2010 use list items as JSON data and consume it in ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to sharepoint.I want to create a json format of a list data and consume it by ajax.I know how to iterate through list items:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["My List"]; 

foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items) 
{ 
    //process
}
```

How can I use this to return result as json and use this result in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

you can directly call sharepoint web services using ajax , use [$().SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) , it provides functions to convert `xml` response to `JSON`  check this example [GetListItems Example](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems) , to convert xml to JSON use this function [$().SPXmlToJson](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPXmlToJson)

Example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").SPXmlToJson({ 
           mapping: {},
           includeAllAttrs: false,
           removeOws: true
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works if you are using this in a CEWP or a feature/web part stored on the SharePoint box.  It will not work from an aspx page.